# How to set up Active Directory in windows 7?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I just installed Remote Server Administrative Tools (RSAT) on windows 7, and turned features on as mentioned in the installation guide. Now the Administrative Tools have been installed and successfully listed in the *All Programs* list of start menu.

I want to set up a local network. I want to create users/passwords, and give them access to shared drives with permissions, etc.

My questions is:

***How do I configure and set up the Active Directory in windows 7 for the first time?***

***Edit 1***

If Active Directory is not for windows 7, why has Microsoft provided RSAT for windows 7? (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Comment: For sharing drives in a local network, just use local users: create every user you need on the Windows 7 machine and grant access rights to the drives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RSAT package available for Windows 7 (and other client systems) only installs the required tools to **remotely manage** several services, including Active Directory; however, **those services still need to be running on actual servers in your network**; those servers must use a server release of the Windows OS (currently Windows Server 2012 R2): client releases don't include services such as Active Directory, DNS, DHCP, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

RSAT is exlusively used to configure services on a Windows Server machine. They are not a directory service in itself.

It's not possible at all to use a non-server version of Windows as AD server.

Comment: Thanks @Sven for your answer. But if it is not for windows 7, why has Microsoft provided RSAT for windows 7? (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Comment: @Omid1989 It's meant to give Administrators remote tools to be able to configure their environment without having to remote into a server.

Comment: Thanks @Zypher for your quick comment. You mean, if an administrator wants to control the server but he doesn't have access to the server computer, he can control it remotely via his personal PC running win7, with RSAT installed. Right ?

Comment: @Omid1989 no, you still need access. RSAT is "REMOTE SERVER Administrator Tools" The tools to be able to REMOTELY ADMINISTER the server. They are there so you can have the same MMC snap-ins as you do on a server, letting you manage it from your primary PC running a client OS

Comment: Thanks @Zypher for your helpful comment. Actually, I'm new to server things, and I'm not familiar with the terminology like snap-ins, MMC, .... But I'm sure what you said is really technologized. :D